# How to Bind events to a function without a DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I've been doing this little hack to achieve what I need to add multiple events at different times to one particular function.

```
$("#handler").bind("click",function(){ alert(1); });
$("#handler").bind("click",function(){ alert(2); });
$("#handler").bind("click",function(){ alert(3); });
```

When I simply call `$("#handler").click()` it fires all those events.

Question is, can I do this without making some arbitrary html object to bind it to?

What is the equivalent to do this with a standard javascript function?

```
function handler(){ alert(1); }
function handler(){ alert(2); }
function handler(){ alert(3); }
handler();
```

^This just fires the last one, and not all 3.  How can I bind multiple events to a function instead of to a DOM element?

Comment: Bind the event only once.

Comment: @Tushar Yes of course, then I wouldn't need to ask the question right?  Problem, the bindings happen at different parts of run-time. But thanks for the input

Comment: have you consider using loop? it fires the last one because the last read function was the same with the first and second one.

Comment: @CodeDemon Not sure how a loop would accomplish binding arbitrary events during different parts in run-time, to one function

Comment: you must use different function name to run different function.

Comment: @CodeDemon That's the point, it has to be one function.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qcre3nxg/1/

Comment: how about one function with 3 events? like 3 alerts?

Comment: You can't have 3 functions with same name in the same scope... the last one will override the previous definitions

Comment: @ArunPJohny The fiddle is something similar that may work,but is this some plugin handling this?

Comment: @RealWorldCoder it is using [jQuery.callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ok thanks, I've never seen this before. But is this the closest thing? There aren't any ways to do this in native javascript, without using jquery or dom elements?

Comment: why not https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qcre3nxg/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny For efficiency I suppose

Comment: So you basically want a container for queuing up multiple (different) functions that you can then trigger (the container) to fire off the member functions, similar to an event listener but without the need for using an arbitrary DOM element as the container. Is that right? If so, a PubSub solution like suggested in one answer may be the way to go, having a way of adding/removing subscribed function objects and firing all of them when the container object fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really just looking for a way to group individual functions together into a larger "function set" that you can then trigger later all at once, this could be achieved via a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object in javascript. Example:

```
// define the Set object that you want to store the functions inside:
var handlerFunctionCollection = new Set();


// add individual functions to the Set:
handlerFunctionCollection.add( function(){ console.log(1); } );
handlerFunctionCollection.add( function(){ console.log(2); } );
handlerFunctionCollection.add( function(){ console.log(3); } );

// trigger all functions in set using forEach on Set 
// and call() method on stored Function object:
handlerFunctionCollection.forEach(function(handlerFunction) {
    if(handlerFunction instanceof Function) {
        handlerFunction.call();
    }
});
```

Note that I'm basing this interpretation of your question based on you saying:

> When I simply call `$("#handler").click()` it fires all those events.

which suggests you aren't actually looking for a way to bind functions directly to an event, but a way to trigger multiple functions in one place, since otherwise you wouldn't be triggering the `click` event manually.

A benefit of using a `Set` over an `Array` object or similar collection is that members of a `Set` are unique, so that if you were try to add the same function multiple times (accidentally or otherwise), the added `Function` object would only occur once in the `Set`, so that it would therefore only get triggered once when triggering the `forEach`, since it would only exist once in the `Set` rather than for each time it was added.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript every function is actually a **Function object**.
   In Javascript if you define multiple functions with the same name then the last one will actually run. JavaScript `functions` are not `polymorphic` like  functions in many other languages where in other languages you might have `funcA(parm1)` and `funcA(parm1, parm2)` as two separate functions with the one that gets run depending on the number of parameters passed.

 

In your case , you need to declare one function in a way that can handle different situations inside the function scope .

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the concept of `Observer` or `Publisher/Subscriber ("PubSub")`.

These are pretty easy to create on your own.
Here's a slightly cleaned version of the application-only code (that might run on DOM-ready, or whatever), to run the demo code below.

```
const trigger = $("#Trigger");
const system = Publisher();

// add my listeners
system
.on("trigger", triggerContentUpdate)
.on("update", updateView)
.on("update", logUpdate); // note how I have two things bound to the same event

// something that kicks off the "trigger" event
// could be a timer, or an AJAX call, or anything else
trigger.onclick = () => system.fire("trigger");
```

Assuming you had a `Publisher` library and had the above listener functions in your app, this is pretty much all of the JS you'd have to write to make the demo below work.

The library I wrote as practice, and the implementation of the demo are below.

```js
/*** LIBRARY CODE ***/

// Channel.js
const Channel = () => {
  const listeners = new Set();

  const channel = {

    listen(listener) {
      listeners.add(listener);
      return channel;
    },

    ignore(listener) {
      listeners.delete(listener);
      return channel;
    },

    notify(data) {
      listeners.forEach(react => react(data));
      return channel;
    }
  };

  return channel;
};

// Publisher.js
const Publisher = () => {
  const channels = {};

  function getChannel(name) {
    const channel = channels[name] || Channel();
    channels[name] = channel;
    return channel;
  }

  const publisher = {

    on(name, subscriber) {
      getChannel(name).listen(subscriber);
      return publisher;
    },

    off(name, subscriber) {
      getChannel(name).ignore(subscriber);
      return publisher;
    },

    fire(name, data) {
      getChannel(name).notify(data);
      return publisher;
    }

  };

  return publisher;
}

/*** END OF LIBRARY CODE ***/



/*** APPLICATION CODE ***/

// const Publisher = require("publisher"); or import Publisher from "publisher";

const $ = selector => document.querySelector(selector);

const trigger = $("#Trigger");
const input = $("#Content");
const output = $("#Result");
const log = $("#Log");

const system = Publisher();

system
  .on("trigger", () => {
    const content = input.value;
    system.fire("update", content);
  })
  .on("update", content => output.value = content)
  // normally, I never use innerHTML, and my logic and view are never attached, but this is dirt-simple now
  .on("update", content => log.innerHTML += `<li>[${ (new Date()).toISOString() }]: ${content}</li>`);

trigger.onclick = () => system.fire("trigger");

/*** END OF APPLICATION CODE ***/
```

```html
<h3>Input</h3>
<div>
  <input id="Content" type="text">
  <button id="Trigger">Update</button>
</div>
<h3>Output</h3>
<output id="Result"></output>

<h3>Log</h3>
<ul id="Log"></ul>
```

Of course, I'm using relatively modern syntax, but nothing that can't be rewritten in older compatible code, or transpiled and given a polyfill, to go all the way down to IE7/8 support.

If I wanted to make some arbitrary object a publisher, I could do that rather quickly as well.

Comment: @RealWorldCoder it's 100% JavaScript. Native, normal, every-day JavaScript. You can replace all arrow functions with old-fashioned `function`, you can replace the `Set` with `[ ]` and add extra checks to not insert duplicate listeners (something a set does for you).  You can replace all `const` with `var`. And you're back at old-fashioned JS. If you'll note, though, if you're running this in, say Chrome or FireFox, or any self-respecting browser, the example should work just fine.

Comment: @RealWorldCoder have a look at http://BabelJS.io which transforms ES6 (the above) into ES3 (IE8+) compatible code, when used in conjunction with a polyfill for objects like `Set` and `Map`

Comment: I only ask because it looks different than what I'm used to seeing. Granted, it may do the trick, just looks much heavier than I would expect to see.

Comment: @RealWorldCoder Heavy? Typically, `Publisher` and `Channel` that I've written there would be a separate JS library (or jQuery plugin). I have written an implementation of basically the system that runs behind `addEventListener`.  Have a look at the bottom dozen lines (where I create `$` and on); that's where I am using the library.

And then have a look at/run the updated version of the snippet, where I  tried to make this a little more apparent. Note that `system` here is just a `Publisher` from the library that I just invented (there are loads of libraries for these, I'm sure).